# Simplify integral $f(x)=e^{-(\frac{(m+1)}{C_1}+\frac{(n)}{C_2})x}\ln(x+1)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

The Proprieties that the authors use [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyoss.png)

This question 
Let $f(x)$ define by
$$
f(x)=e^{-(\frac{(m+1)}{C_1}+\frac{(n)}{C_2})x}\ln(x+1)
$$ 
I would like to compute the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

So we use $y=x+1$ and $u=(\frac{(m+1)}{C_1}+\frac{(n)}{C_2})$, the integral becom
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-u(y-1)}\ln (y)dy=e^u\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-uy}\ln (y)dy
$$
Use the following result 
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-uy}\ln (y)dy=-\frac{1}{u}E_i(-u)
$$
SO the final result is 
$$
-\frac{e^u}{u}E_i(-u)
$$
were $E_i$ is the exponential integral.
But were i found the integral the result was 
$$
-\frac{e^u}{u}E_i(u)
$$
No "$-$" inside the exponential integral $E_i$? why

This is the Problem

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb6bJ.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnXxG.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnJAq.png)

The refrence [38] definition is

[See here [38] defenition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3qdS.png)

Comment: I guess you mean $\mathrm{Ei}(u)$ and not $E_i(u)$

Comment: yes my question that the authors write $\frac{-e^u}{u}E_i(u)$, but i found $\frac{-e^u}{u}E_i(-u)$ ? Dose exist are proprieties $E_i(-u)=E_i(u)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathrm{Ei}$ and $E_i$ are different functions (see https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2). For $u>0$ your integral is 
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-uy}\ln (y)dy=+\frac{1}{u}E_1(u)
$$
**Addendum:** With `int(exp(-u*y)*ln(y),y=1..infinity) with u>0` Wolfram Alpha returns $\frac{\Gamma(0,u)}{u}$ for the integral , which is the same as my result using $\Gamma(0,u) = E_1(u)$ (see http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/27/02/0002/)

Comment: I will ad the picture in which the authors use

Comment: It all depends on the sign of $u$. Therefore I added the condition $u>0$. For $u<0$ you have  $\Re E_1(u) = −\Re \mathrm{Ei}(−u)$ and an imaginary part.

Comment: I have  $u>0$ so what is the correct answer is it

Comment: $$
-\frac{e^u}{u}E_i(-u)
$$
or
$$
-\frac{e^u}{u}E_i(u)
$$ or $$ +\frac{e^u}{u}E_1(u)$$

Comment: The authors use the second is it correct or now

Comment: A last time $\mathrm{Ei}$ **is not** $E_i!$ I added the result from WA.

Comment: I add all the equation but i think the author mistake instade of using $E_1$ hi use Ei

Comment: I agree whit your result but what about the result in Figure 3?

Comment: What is there definition in [38]. For a some more details see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html especially formula (6).

Comment: The definition is the picture See here

Comment: However thanks so much for helping me i will ask the authors about it and i hop that they will answer me.

Comment: [38] Seems to come from Gradshteyn/Ryzhik. They only list $\mathrm{Ei}$ in chap. 8.2 and not the other exponential integrals like $E_1, E_2$. And as already hinted for $u>0$ you have $-\mathrm{Ei}(-u) = E_1(u)$. (This relation is mentioned by G/R  in the introductionary 'Use of the tables / Exponential and Related Integrals').

Comment: ok You and I we say that is −Ei$(−u)=E_1(u)$., so the resault in paper is wrong i gess